# How to avoid or skip a test from testng or reportng report

Tags: testng

I have a test which setups the environment variable for group of tests in testng, i want to skip this test count from the testng report.

my testng.xml looks like:

```
<suite name="sanity"  verbose="1">
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter"/>
        <listener class-name="org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter"/>
    </listeners>
 <test name="tes1">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.group.SantiyStartUp"/>
            <class name="com.group.Test1"/>
            <class name="com.group.Test2"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

SanityStartUp sets the static variable  `"environment"`  as `"Sanity"` and `Test1` and `Test2` classes, will check if the `environment` variable is `Sanity` then do some actions.

it is working fine, but my concern is SanityStartUp test displaying in the report as one test, which i want to avoid.

Any one please help me on this.

Comment: Why not move the setup logic to the BeforeSuite or even the BeforeTest method?

Comment: Is it through Parameterization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start from simple solution which were provided for you in comments - use `@BeforeSuite` or even the `@BeforeTest` instead of `@Test`.

Also you need to understand how listeners adding works in TestNG. You may add listener anywhere in your code, testng.xml, or classpath and it would be applied to all classes and tests. So you may try to edit you listener, to ignore some classes or tests.

And finally you can pass them as system environment variables for JVM using command line and read them in test.